# HttpRequest.BodyPublisher cannot find symbol

Tags: java, java-10

> Error:(226, 34) java: cannot find symbol 
>   symbol:   variable BodyPublisher 
>   location: class jdk.incubator.http.HttpRequest

```
private static JSONObject sendRequest(JSONObject json) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client;
    InetSocketAddress proxy = getRandomProxy();

    if(proxy == null) {
        client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    } else {
        client = HttpClient.newBuilder().proxy(ProxySelector.of(proxy)).build();
    }

    HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest
            .newBuilder(new URI(BASE_URL))
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .timeout(TIMEOUT_DURATION)
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublisher.fromString(json.toString()))
            .build();

    HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = client.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandler.asString());
    String jsonResponse = httpResponse.body();

    return new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
}
```

module-info.java:

```
module MyProject {

    requires jdk.incubator.httpclient;

}
```

I've tried it with OpenJDK 10 and Oracle JDK 10 on Linux.

Comment: Works fine for me in a modularised code. Could you share a reproducible instance or further details of how you are executing the code?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Idea 2017.3.2 with JDK 10 (readme: [https://hastebin.com/setuyexiqo.ini]. For example this won't work for me: `System.out.println(HttpRequest.BodyPublisher.fromString("Test").hashCode());`

Answer (score 0):

You could check the target bytecode version of your module (**File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler> Java Compiler**), it should be set to 10.
You might also check the project SDK and language level settings under **File > Project Settings > Project** and **File > Project Settings > Modules**.